# How to set an env variable in Ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I want to set an env variable inside my build.xml target

```
<target name="run-tenantManagement" depends="jar">
   <property name="SIMV3.1" value="${SIMV3.1}" />
    //now here i want to do something like setenv SIMV3.1 true
</target>
```

and Inside my java code, I want to access it using :

```
if("true".equals(System.getenv("SIMV3.1")){
//do something
}
```

Kindly suggest. I have tried many things but none of them worked.Also, there is no main() method as the framework is testng based and test cases are invoked using testNG.

Comment: You cant. Why not System parameter?

Comment: @SMA because environment variables propagate to subprocesses, which is the behavior that I need (pass values to processes invoked a regression test run by a JUnit runner started by Ant via `junit` task). Processes can modify their environment via `setenv()` (system call), that is how shells modify their environment that gets passed to subprocesses. Ant _should_ expose this, but it looks like maybe it doesn't. Environment variables also work for non-Java processes.

Answer (score 2):

How are you running your program? If it is using exec with fork, then you can pass new environment to it

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html.

Example from  the page..

```
<exec executable="emacs">
  <env key="DISPLAY" value=":1.0"/>
</exec>
```

Consider following build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="myjava" basedir=".">
  <target name="myjava">
    <!--default , if nothing comes from command line -->
    <property name="SIMV3.1" value="mydefaultvalue"/>

    <echo message="Value of SIMV3.1=${SIMV3.1}"/>
    <java fork="true" classname="EnvPrint">
      <env key="SIMV3.1" value="${SIMV3.1}"/>
    </java>
  </target>
</project>
```

and small java program

```
public class EnvPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("SIMV3.1"));
    }
}
```

With out any command line:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: C:\build.xml

myjava:
     [echo] Value of SIMV3.1=mydefaultvalue
     [java] mydefaultvalue
```

With some arguments from command line:

```
$ ant -DSIMV3.1=commandlineenv
Buildfile: C:\build.xml

myjava:
     [echo] Value of SIMV3.1=commandlineenv
     [java] commandlineenv
```

Comment: I am running using ant -DSIMV3.1=true <targetName>

Comment: In my case, I have several targets that need the same variable and I don't want to have to add it explicitly in each instance (DRY).

Answer (score 1):

**Immutability:** In ant, properties are immutable:

```
<property name="env.foo" value="your value goes here"/>
```

won't work.

**Mutability:** But variables are mutable, so this works:

```
<variable name="env.foo" value="your value goes here"/>
```

Modified Code :

```
<target name="run-tenantManagement" depends="jar">
    <variable name="env.SIMV3.1" value="${SIMV3.1}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: If I try this, I am getting the following error:

 Problem: failed to create task or type variable
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Comment: Same error for me... using ant 1.10.14 on windows 11, which is the current version of ant

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Place your variable in a `build.properties` file and reference it in your build.xml. Then you can pass the variable... But I think it would be much better to use **[Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)** if you need to have better control over multiple environment configurations.

#### build.properties

```
var=${val};
```

#### build.xml

---

```
 <property file="build.properties"/>     
 <property name="var" value="${val}"/>
   <target name="init">
      <echo>${var}</echo>
  </target>
```

#### CLI

---

```
 ant -Dvar=value
```